# C# GeckoFX web browser - Remove http from textbox

Tags: c#, http, browser, textbox, geckofx

I'm working on a web browser. Once the textbox isn't selected anymore it should remove http:// and the last /. To do that I'm using the leave method of the textbox. This code works perfectly fine with the normal WebBrowser.

```
        if (W.DocumentTitle != "")
        {
            q.Text = "" + W.Url;
            q.Text = q.Text.Replace("http://www.", "");
            q.Text = q.Text.Replace("https://www.", "");
            q.Text = q.Text.Replace("http://", "");
            q.Text = q.Text.Replace("https://", "");
            if (q.Text.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                q.Text = q.Text.Substring(0, q.Text.Length - 1);
            }
        }
```

In GeckoFX however the textbox still displays http:// and /!?!?!

Comment: In what context are you using this code-block?

Comment: This code is used if you leave the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want take only domain name try this

```
q.Text = myGeckoWebBrowser.Url.Domain;
```

If you want only the local path try this

```
q.Text = myGeckoWebBrowser.Url.LocalPath;
```

And if you want both try this

```
q.Text = myGeckoWebBrowser.Url.Domain + '' + myGeckoWebBrowser.Url.LocalPath;
q.Text = q.Text.Replace("www","")'
```

I hope it helps